# Crystal Reports Page Width Rendered Incorrectly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am having a strange issue with a VS2008 application we are distributing where the numerous Crystal Reports are all displayed in the viewer at half width, making most of the reports completely unreadable.  The reports also print half page width when printing is attempted.

The frustrating thing is, MOST target machines display and print reports perfectly.  It's just SOME target machines (maybe 2-3% overall) that do this.

Just looking for possible ideas and things to check for.  We install the CR runtime with our MSI installer.  What would happen if another application on the machine had already installed CR and it was the wrong version?  Just fishing for ideas.

Any help or suggestions anyone could offer would be much appreciated.  A few of our customers are very frustrated.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this happen when the paper size/orientation isn't 8 1/2 X 11 portrait and/or the printer driver that was used by the developer doesn't exist on the client machines

To fix this I usually try and pick a Software printer From the printer setup (PDF Creator Window XPS Document writer).

After I've applied this printer I go back and select no printer checkbox.

I don't know why this works but I'm guessing that the printer driver is needed for the intial layout and margins and that the no printer removes dependencies on the developer's driver.

Answer (score 1):

Check their printer driver and the page setup.