# Crystal Reports off-center Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-xi

We use crystal reports 11.5 and for some reason one of our Report files all the reports are off center in the report preview and when you export to PDF but this happens on ONLY a couple PC's, others work fine.

Any thoughts? Any machine specific settings for Crystal Reports that handles this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default printer settings?  report page setup?

Comment: Well they're not printing to pdf but exporting to pdf from Crystal Reports Viewer

Comment: so it's ok in the Crystal Viewer and only bad on some .pdfs after exporting?

Comment: No it's off center in the viewer too. It's quite the mystery!

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729760/crystal-reports-page-width-rendered-incorrectly/3729799#3729799

Comment: Thanks Beth, didn't see that post. Figured it out.